# Which is the first movie to show intelligent zombies?

Tags: history-of, zombie

In the movie *Army of the Dead* the zombies have the ability to think and plan, in other words the zombies are intelligent. I would like to know which was the first movie or TV series to show intelligent zombies?

Comment: One might even argue that an intelligent zombie is not a zombie.

Comment: First question that comes to mind is when do we define that a zombie is intelligent. Like, in some depictions, they can't even open a door. In some others, they can climb a ladder (which to me is quite a feat). Do you mean, when they're more than just ferals that act like beasts?

Comment: Does _[Frankenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein_(1931_film))_ (1931) count?

Comment: I mean Zombies who can think and act and react to things happening around them.

Comment: Related: [What work of scifi broke the mold of zombies being undead voodoo minions and depicted them as mindless maneaters?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/26432/31394)

Comment: Indeed very related, because original zombies were by no means some undead corpses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to suggest the 1985 *[Return of the Living Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_the_Living_Dead)* where the zombies, while generally shambling reanimated corpses, retain enough smarts to set ambushes and to request to "send more paramedics" after they eat the first batch.